# Voltage Regulator that gives an output of 12V and 10A

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

I'm looking for a voltage regulator that takes 9V-20V input voltage and gives an output of 12V and 10A. I found a couple of buck-boost regulators that can do that but i just cant seem to simulate it. I need something that i can simulate in multisim or LTSpice so that i am 100% sure that it would work in real life. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Be aware that there are very few circuits which work in simulation which cannot be made to fail "in real life" by improper construction, and switching power circuits are among the worst offenders.

Answer (score 1):

Linear Technology list 5 parts: [Buck-Boost](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Buck-Boost_Regulators#!1646_Buck-Boost%7CSEPIC!1032_%3C=9!1033_%3E=20!1105_%3C=12!1034_%3E=12!1035_38.7:60!1107_10:25!2086_%3E32!vinmin_9!vinmax_20!vout_12!iout_10!vout2_!iout2_!vout3_!iout3_)

LTSpice IV has all 5 models and even 5 jigs (complete circuits) for you to evaluate.

Comment: Not cheap.... Quite pricy...